# Is it possible to modify the contents of the window.location without redirecting the page?

Tags: javascript

I need to make a modification of the whole `window.location` (the whole route) without updating something similar to `history.pushState` but I do not find some viable way to do it.

I've tried to make the modification with `definegetter` but so I observe this function only serves for document type parameters. Is it possible to modify the location parameter with javascript?

Comment: Even if English isn't your native language, your question deserves quite a bit more attention to punctuation and grammar to become comprehensible.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to use window.location in the manner you were hoping.

Changing the page's url will cause the browser to issue a new request.

The most common approach to use is for your server to instead pre-prepare the url using something like [URL Rewrite for IIS](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) if you want to have some customization.

Answer (score 1):

You would use `window.location.hash` and hash parameters like `your-page?#id=1,user=gabriel`. Keep in mind that `window.location.hash` is a just plain text. In order to change a portion of it, you'll need to parse it, change a value, and *stringify* it back again.

Also, you might do stuff whenever hash parameters change:

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function() {
   // Do stuff here whenever hash changes
});
```